# Firefox PDF previewer assign Firefox tab title, as PDF's meta title and PDF's file name, how change

Tags: pdf, firefox, tabs, filenames, title

I am not interested any meta title of PDFs while viewing them on Firefox's PDF previewer. I only want to see PDF files' names on Firefox tabs.

Any about:config > pdfjs setting related to it?